# models Django invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am new to Django, I am tring to make a Blog here is my models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.user_name


class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category


class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="No title")
    body = models.TextField(default="None")
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, default=1)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default="None")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField(default="")
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
```

but when i run the command:

> python manage.py migrate

i get the

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'

I tried to delete the old migration file and migrate again but I got the same error, what should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `default="None"`, specify `null=True` to allow null for foreign key:

```
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True)
```

Comment: I did it but the same problem, I noticed something that in the trace back all the directories are referring to python 3.5 and I suppose to be using python 2.7! do u think this is related?

Comment: @HossamSalah, Delete the migrations file (<app>/migration/000n_migration_file.py) and regenerate it.

Comment: @HossamSalah, You're welcome. Happy Python programming.